# flying saucer 8 and command line

Tags: unix, command-line, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I wondering is it possible to use unix command line with flying saucer for the xhtml to pdf conversion? If so, how? I have looked on the documentation and can't find how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## Flying Saucer R8

It is possible using [Flying Saucer R8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/downloads):

```
java -cp core-renderer.jar:iText-2.0.8.jar:xml-apis-xerces-2.9.1.jar 
         org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ToPDF http://your_url_here file.pdf
```

## Flying Saucer R9

A similar approach to the following can be used for Flying Saucer R8:

1. Create a directory structure such as:

```
    flyingsaucer/
    ├── bin
    │   └── flyingsaucer.sh
    └── lib
        ├── flying-saucer-core-9.1.16.jar
        ├── flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.16.jar
        ├── iText-2.1.7.jar
        └── xml-apis-xerces-2.9.1.jar
```

2. The shell script `flyingsaucer.sh` includes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )"
FS_LIB="$SCRIPT_DIR/../lib"

java -cp "$FS_LIB/*" org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ToPDF $1 $2
```

3. Run the shell script such as:

   ```
   ./flyingsaucer/bin/flyingsaucer.sh https://www.w3.org w3c.pdf
   ```

A PDF version of the web page is created.

Comment: Note that the `:` characters in the classpath must be replaced by `;` on Windows